# append a jQuery object (that is some html with events on it) inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
container.append('<tr><td></td></tr>')
```

and I need to put this object inside the td (above):

```
var myobj = $('<div>hi</div>').click(function(e){...});
```

anybody knows a good way of doing this ?

Comment: [Chuck Norris](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/) is asking for help..!? ...I'm scared... **@.@**

Comment: I would suggest using event delegation instead of a handler inside each cell... http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: @JuanMendes it's just one cell that has this

Answer (score 1):

Something like, select the last TR because you can add more then one. And then add it to the first TD.

```
container.find("tr:last td").append(myobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  container.find('td').append(myobj);
```